# Where am I going wrong about Django Filtering

Tags: python, django, filter

I want to create a search bar for my flash cards, I want to filter and this is my views.py folder but the code I wrote is not working.

I have word cards in my database (flash cards for foreign language memorization). I want to be able to search in these cards specifically, I want the card belonging to the word I typed in the input to appear.

This is the my search input in my html page:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="form-outline">
        <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" />
        <label class="form-label">Search</label>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

---

Here I tried to get the value entered in the input with 'search'
The name of the card in my database 'tr' in the filter

---

```
def ingilizce(request):

    if 'search' in request.GET:
        search = request.GET['search']
        words = english.objects.filter(tr=search)

    else:
        words = english.objects.all()

    randomclass = random.choice(
        ['bg-success', 'bg-primary', 'bg-dark', 'bg-warning', 'bg-primary'])

    paginator = Paginator(words, 6) 
    page_number = request.GET.get('page', 1)  

    try:
        page = paginator.page((page_number))
    except: 
        page = paginator.page(1)

    return render(request, 'english.html', {'words': page, 'randomclass': randomclass})
```

---

Here is my models.py

---

```
from django.db import models


    class english(models.Model):
        tr = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="tr")
        ing = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="ing")
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.tr
```

---

urls.py

---

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('english', views.ingilizce, name='english'),
    path('addWord', views.addWord, name='add'),
    path('deleteWord/<int:id>', views.deleteWord, name='deleteWord'),
]
```

Comment: Hey @ced3j by not working what does that mean? Do you have an error message? Could you include examples of what is in the database and what you are expecting to get?

Comment: Try  `search = request.GET.get('search', None)` then `if search: ... else: ...`

Comment: I tried to be a little more descriptive

Comment: Yes i saw, but try my comment and let us know

Comment: And also `words = english.objects.filter(tr=search)` will match the records that exactly the value of `tr` equal to `search`. Pay attention

Comment: This didn't work I guess I'm doing it wrong
(
    search = request.GET.get('search', None)
    if search:
        words = english.objects.filter(tr=search)

    else:
        words = english.objects.all()

Is this correct usage?

Comment: In this case you might want `words= english.objects.filter(tr__icontains=search)` ?

Comment: I tried tr__icontains too but nothing happened

Comment: Try to add a print statement after `words = english.objects.filter(tr=search)` : `print(words)` and look in the console. Also add it to the `else` block

Comment: Now, when I add new word I see this in console:
`<QuerySet [<english: test>]>` --- 
But when I use search, there is no print operation.

Comment: Stop the server and go to the console: `./manage.py shell` and import the english model: `from .models import english`. Make a query with filter. `words = english.objects.filter(tr__icontains='test')` ... what is the result ?

Comment: would help if you show the model... also in your view my want to print `search` and confirm its there

Comment: I tried shell and got an error like this `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: "'__name__' not in globals"` and I will edit my post for the models.py

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `in` query filter :-

```
def ingilizce(request):
search = request.GET.get('search', None)
print("Input search value : {}".format(search)) # for debugging
if search:
    words = english.objects.filter(tr__in=search)
else:
    words = english.objects.all()
```

You need to call the view using JS like below :-

```
var search = document.getElementById("search");
search.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    var url = '/english/?search='+search.value  // place your url here
    window.open(url, "_self");
  }
});
```

Comment: I got this result on console
`Input search value : None`

Comment: This means you search string is not reaching to the view, which method you are using GET or POST to submit the search string. Could you please share your URL.py content and HTML form.

Comment: Oh I didn't use any form... and I added my urls.py. I also tried adding a form to html after you wrote it, but it still didn't work. (I tried both post and get )

Comment: As you are not using form, and when hit the button nothing will go to the view.
if you dont want to use form then you need to use javascript to make call to you view.